# Validator selection

Tags: validators

When validating a block, do validators know who the other validators are, prior to voting?  Does the proposer know the other validators prior to proposing a block?

If so, that could lead to collusion right?  I.e. there's a non zero probability a committee has > 2/3 of validators from a colluding cartel.  They choose to validate incorrectly for nefarious purposes.  It could be much worse, if the proposer is also in the cartel and is aware of who the other validators will be.  If the proposer knows that the cartel will control the next validating committee, the proposer could propose a large transaction right?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the context of this question is Eth2. Much of the answer is going to be based on [this](https://ethos.dev/beacon-chain/) excellent article on the beacon chain.

In the current beacon chain epochs are 6 minutes and 24 seconds long. Every epoch there is a shuffling. Not just that, but the results of the shuffle are taken from the entire pool of validators. There are currently >100k validators (source: [beaconcha.in](https://beaconcha.in), from which a cartel would need to control 2/3. Even with the minimum requirement of 128 validators per epoch, it would be improbable to control that much of an epoch. (The article linked above links to another article explaining the math behind this claim: [source](https://medium.com/@chihchengliang/minimum-committee-size-explained-67047111fa20)).

Add to this that if the cartel is caught colluding, they'll get slashed. To use an analogy attributed to Vlad Zamfir, this would be like if in Proof-of-Work a miner's hardware combusted if they were caught participating in a 51% attack. This puts pressure on the incentive to collaborate with the cartel, as if the cartel fails, the collaborator's reserves will also be destroyed.

That being said, your conclusion is correct. *If* a cartel controls 2/3 of an epoch, they can propose malicious blocks. (Not unlike how if a cartel controls 51% of the hashpower in PoW, they can do the same.)